# python then I create event in outlook, time have +1h

Tags: python, outlook, icalendar

I have problem with outlook, about two weeks ago, started messing up with time. Always then I create event in outlook calendar showing +1h time.

Let me explain it more clearly

For example I create event UK TIME 3PM

Then I print event time or check database I got

```
event date 2021-07-29 15:00:00
```

It seems all good, but then I check I outlook my event time have +1h. In outlook my time zone
[image]

So here is not problem. In outlook my event time is 16h like picture bellow.

[image]

In code then generating event are set time zone Europe/London.

```
tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/London")
```

Any knows where is the problem? I using icalendar for creating event.

Comment: Your program seems to be using current UK time, which is UTC+1, because it's summer. But your outlook seems to be set to UTC+0.

Comment: But, time zone switch from UTC+1 (BTS) or UTC+0  is not automatic ? How fix what?

Comment: @khelwood then i set  ```tz = pytz.timezone('UTC')``` it not helping..

Comment: I don't think the setting in outlook is the problem as Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London is the correct timezone.  plus there is a separate option in the drop down list for just UTC. @mausasu1234 do you have the ICS String for the event?